# clickable pdf to order parts

Tags: xpages, acrobat

On an Xpage I have a clickable pdf with article numbers on it.(with the link tool in Acrobat)
When the user clicks on the article number I would like to find a way to put this article number in a viewscope (so the user will be able to order it)
How do I have to make my link and how do I get this info into the viewscope.

Answer (score 3):

Write an XAgent (e.g. ArticleNumber.xsp) which saves an URL parameter into sessionScope. Create link URLs in pdf which deliver article number as URL parameter.

Example URL:

```
http://server1/database.nsf/ArticleNumber.xsp?article=12345
```

Example XAgent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    rendered="false">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         sessionScope.article = param.article}]]>
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
</xp:view>
```

You have to use sessionScope for this approach. Instead of only setting sessionScope to current article number you could "collect" the clicked article numbers in sessionScope and later open a page which shows all selected articles.

Comment: This would be the code to collect article numbers: `try {
 sessionScope.article.push(param.article);
  } catch(e) {
   sessionScope.article = [param.article];
  }`

Comment: Just in case you want to show the article (clicked in pdf) in an XPage you would use a normal XPage and get the article document with the help of `param.article`. In this case you don't need a scope variable at all.

Comment: Knut, thank you. This seems to be working.The only thing; with every click the user leaves the page. In the xagent I've put an afterpageload to bring the user back where he left, which goes fast but still the user will notice this. Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: You could add `target="_blank"` to your links so they would open XAgent in a new tab. You'd add a window.close() in onClientLoad event and set rendered to true. But, still noticeable to users...